Distribution of censored sample
This is a concept question - I'm trying to make sure that I really understand the mechanism and consequences of such mode of sampling.
If I take an iid random sample from known distribution (say Standard Normal) but I censor it e.g. as follows: I ignore any observation that follows a negative value, otherwise I record it - will I end up with Standard Normal?

"Ignoring" an observation based on its value is truncation, not censoring, in the definitions used in statistics. The difference: if you ignore an observation (truncation) it provides no information at all for your modeling. "Censoring" means that you only know limits to the value for an observation, but you still know that there was an observation with a value somewhere within those limits. See the second paragraph of this Wikipedia entry.

I'm not totally sure I understand what you mean by "follows a negative value". If what you have in mind is some iterative sampling like :

you draw iteratively 1, -1.5, 0.5, 4, -2, 3 ;
you keep only 1, -1.5, 4, -2 (removing 0.5 and 3 since they "follow" negative values).

Then yes, you will end up with a standard normal distribution.
To convince yourself of that : if we denote $f$ the density function, then for all $i$, $f(X_i|X_{i-1}) = f(X_i)$ since the samples are independant. In particular, $f(X_i|1\{X_{i-1}\} > 0) = f(X_i)$.
